# m2e lifecycle mapping: delegating plugin execution

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

According to [m2e wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered):

> m2e matches plugin executions to actions using combination of plugin
>   groupId, artifactId, version range and goal. There are three basic
>   actions that m2e can be instructed to do with a plugin execution --
>   ignore, execute and delegate to a project configurator.

Further I can read that to ignore a plugin I need to do:

```
<pluginExecution>
   <pluginExecutionFilter>
      <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
      <versionRange>[2.0.5,)</versionRange>
      <goals>
         <goal>process</goal>
      </goals>
   </pluginExecutionFilter>
   <action>
      <delegate />
   </action>
</pluginExecution>
```

So it seems logical that to delegate execution I should do the same but with:

```
<action>
     <delegate />
</action>
```

But it doesn't work. I'm getting following error:

`No enum constant org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.PluginExecutionAction.delegate`

So what is the way to delegate plugin execution? Should I just omit `pluginExecution` element for plugins that I want to delegate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding to the [M2E compatible maven plugins](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_compatible_maven_plugins). There are only

```
1. <ignore/> mapping 
2. <execute/> mapping
```

There is no mentioned tag for delegate.

If I understand correctly, It is a default configuration without any required configuration. It's just let the Eclipse M2E / M2E extension to decide. Please note, for me, I'm using the "***m2e project configurators for Eclipse WTP***" from JBoss for working with the web project. You may need to use some M2E extension which is matched with your requirement.

I always use the ignore for managing the customized resources and it work correctly.

Update:

At the Eclipse, please click menu ***Windows ---> preferences --> Maven --->  Discovery***. Then click the "***Open Catalog***" button. The system will give you a list of extension (m2e connector) for installing. For example, there are the *Android connector, antlr, AspectJ* and so on. I hope that there may be an extension which will help you to achieve the requirement.